# How to analyze whether a PDF file is valid?

Tags: pdf, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-office-2007

I have been running into problems with Office2007-generated PDF files. You can read all about it [here](https://superuser.com/questions/362502/powerpoint-2007-slides-are-only-partially-converted-to-pdf-since-sp3).

> TL;DR: Some PDFs generated from PPTX files using
>   the "Save as PDF/XPS..." add-in are rendered only partially and trigger
>   error messages in Adobe Reader/Acrobat Pro.

After trying many other options outlined in @harrymc's answer to my other question, and after confirmation from other users who have encountered the same problem, I have decided to get Microsoft support involved, which is quite expensive (€299 + taxes which you only get refunded if the support incident uncovers a bug in an MS product, and if support decides that it's in fact a bug).

My problem now is that in the first return call, MS tech support suggested that if only Adobe Reader/Acrobat are having a problem with the file, but Foxit or Chrome can render it correctly, then it's Adobe's problem, not theirs. So now it looks like I need to be able to *prove* that the generated PDF is in fact invalid.

In my other question, @harrymc provided an error message from GhostScript which suggests to me that there is in fact an error in the PDF. But can I really take this as evidence? Is there something like an official PDF validator that can point out exactly what's wrong with my file? Or with Adobe?

For reference, here's [one file that's causing these problems](http://www.pietzckers.de/pptx/Slide.pdf).

**UPDATE:**

MS tech support has been able to reproduce the problem (even in their own XPS viewer), and they agree it's a bug (although they called it a "limitation", gotta remember this), so I won't have to pay for the incident. They will pass it on to the developers, but couldn't guarantee a fix and recommended an upgrade to Office 2010. I'll have to see if my university will play along with this - our standard is currently Office 2007, but I know my license is also valid for 2010.

Comment: It looks OK in the default mac application for viewing PDF files.

Comment: @Nifle: As it does in Foxit or Chrome's internal PDF viewer. My guess is they just ignore the errors. At least that's my hope, otherwise goodbye €360...:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Adobe validator (Preflight in Acrobat X Pro):

[[image]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I08Er.png)

I don't see how much more official you can get. That happened on a "Report PDF syntax issues" in Preflight. The same thing when I tried to test for PDF/A validity. The report process aborts rather than continuing, as it would do for minor errors. There is no response on the numerous Adobe forum posts about this error.

Opening the file in Notepad++ and ripping out every stream (`stream` to `endstream` inclusive) leads to a blank file that does not report an error on opening and only a few minor syntax errors in Preflight (related to the missing streams). Obviously there's something invalid in/about one of those streams, perhaps an invalid control character or something. I don't know much about the PDF format.

Also, PDF creation using the built-in tool works perfectly on your presentation in PowerPoint 2010. It appears only 2007 SP3 is affected - as you found yourself, no previous version was and no later version is. Depending on Microsoft's policy, this may or may not warrant a bugfix. It could be that the encoding used in 2007 SP3's version for images is not fully supported by Adobe.

**Was the file you provided exported with the "ISO 19005-1 compliant (PDF/A)" option checked? If not, could you provide one that is?**

Unless the file was exported as a standards compliant format (that option is unchecked by default!), it is not necessarily a 'bug', unless they explicitly say Adobe Acrobat/Reader should be able to open their PDFs - especially when some programs can. You may be fighting an uphill battle for a refund.

Comment: The [ISO-19005-1 compliant version](http://www.pietzckers.de/pptx/Slide2.pdf) looks even worse. I had tried that before submitting the bug report. However, semi-good news: MS has acknowledged this as a "limitation" of Office 2007 SP3, so I don't have to pay for the support incident.

Comment: That's interesting. MS really botched it, then. You said you have access to Adobe Acrobat Pro, perhaps try its Create PDF function in its Office Add-in? That usually works well. Glad to hear you got a refund.

Answer (score 3):

Before shelling out €360, I would check to see whether the problem was already fixed in Office 2010.

If you wish to get an answer from the specialists, I suggest posting the question to [GhostScript Bugzilla](http://bugs.ghostscript.com/). You could simply ask why they do not accept legal PDF created by Office 2007. They will probably tell you exactly why the PDF is wrong and maybe even how to fix it.

This will require you to open a Bugzilla account.

I have verified that the problem is still happening on the latest GhostScript version 9.05.
You could include the image below with your bug report :

[image]

Comment: Thanks! As for the €360, it's too late now - you can't even start a bug report without up-front payment (but my university will pick up the bill if MS refuse to acknowledge this as a bug, so I won't be hurt personally by this). After your previous analysis, I was certain it's a bug, but MS have managed to instill some fear, uncertainty and doubt into me.

Comment: If MS Support cannot fix your problem **with Office 2007** (which will really surprise me if they could), you might be able to ask for a refund. I don't think that pointing you to Office 2010 counts as a solution.

Comment: Well, my university only provides Office 2007 for now; I guess they're going to skip 2010...

Comment: harrymc has a good point - I tried with your presentation in PowerPoint 2010, it seems to work perfectly (Adobe Acrobat X Pro, which pops up an error and fails to render correctly on your sample PDF). And MS doesn't seem nice about bug reports...

Comment: You could maybe [try Office 2010](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/try/) free for 60 days, in order to create your presentation. If you install it in a VM, you could maybe repeat this operation later again when needed. Anyway, a VM is recommended, since having two versions of Office installed side-by-side on the same computer is not without some problems.

Comment: @Bob: Do you mean that with PPT 2010 the generated PDF works or doesn't work in Adobe X?

Comment: @harrymc I mean the 2010 one I generated works, the 2007 one Tim provided did not. Also, I tried running a Preflight validation, which came up with "An error occurred while parsing a contents stream. Unable to analyse the PDF file.". The same happens on "Report PDF syntax issues" - something *unexpected* breaks, keeping in mind Acrobat should accept and report minor errors during validation. Tim, was your file generated with the "ISO 19005-1 compliant (PDF/A)" option selected (during export)?